# bash file: cronjob vs manual, why are they different?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script that runs every five minutes. Among other things it runs php scripts reading on existing files, and at the end it sends an email. When run manually, it does the job. When the cronjob runs, it partially completes the task. The code below:

```
DIR="/somedir/" 
php ${DIR}client.php $DIR  
cat ${DIR}alert_list.txt | uniq | while read alert; 
do  
   if [ -s ${DIR}alerts/$alert.txt ]; then
        # send the email.           
        echo "Sending email for..."$alert >> ${DIR}email.txt    
        DETAILFILE="tools/"$alert
        DETAILFILEP=${DETAILFILE}".txt"             
        php ${DIR}email.php $alert  
   fi 
done 
echo 'search completed.'
```

in 'cronjob mode' it never gets to the 'do' statement. In manual mode it does everything.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean "it never gets to the 'do' statement"? It hangs at the initial `php` call? How do you know that? I'm assuming you never see `search completed` in the cron logs or something? What do you get when cron runs if you add `set -x` to the script? Is `php` in a default `$PATH` location so cron can find it? Have you looked at the debugging suggestions on the [tag:crontab] wiki?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue within the PHP scripts. Relative calls to files which are located in other paths get missed when it runs automatically. Apparently, it runs from somewhere else, so it could not progress because of the missing input files created by initial php script.

Thanks.

Comment: Cron jobs run in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the manual run and the cron run in bash is that in case of a cron the .bash* files are not sourced initially, and hence it might happen some of the required settings (Eg: PATH) are different.

And also, (replying to your previous comment) The PWD in case of a cron is $HOME, so the needed files as you mentioned are not picked, whereas in case of manual run it picks from the path you run.

Hope this helps.